# Anylogic: Fixed seed, but not reproducible runs if pedestrian library is used

Tags: java, anylogic

I use a road traffic example, which includes pedestrian library too. Before I add ped blocks, using a fixed seed resulted in reproducible runs which helped me a lot for fixing bugs. But since I've added ped blocks, even using a fixed seed, no two runs are the same. And unfortunately a rare error is thrown and I cannot handle it due to not being able to check the real condition of system when error is occurred. So what can I do to solve this problem?

Best Regards.

Comment: can confirm this seems to happen. No idea why, might want to reach out to their support. However, I could imagine that the ped library has some innate randomness (just like real people) that you cannot turn off. Seems weird, though. Keep us posted, interested in what you find out.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, I thought the same, a probable internal randomness of ped library. So any idea how can I trace my bug in such cases?

Comment: nope, maybe support@anylogic.com has an idea... :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pedestrian library evaluates the pedestrian forces in parallel, using all available processors/cores. In this case reproducibility is not guaranteed. You can use the only core for the model execution, in this case the experiment should be reproducible. The number of processors is defined in menu:

Tools - Preferences - Runtime - Number of processors for parallel execution: 1